# Is there a wait function in CSS?

Tags: css, wait

I'm trying to make a animation that makes a `div` element 10 pixels bigger when hovering and 10 pixels smaller when not hovering. The only problem is that when hovering, it plays the animation, and the element gets 10 pixels bigger as expected, but then the animation ends and the element returns to its original size.

This is the code currently:

```css
.box_1 {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.box_1:hover {
  animation-name: bigger;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

.box_1:not(hover) {
  animation_name: bigger;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes bigger {
  from {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
  }
  to {
    width: 310px;
    height: 410px;
  }
}
```

I've tried playing the animation then pausing it, but I'd need a wait function. This probably can be easily solved with JavaScript, but I'm trying not to use it (because I'm lazy).

Comment: animation-delay ?

Comment: @-G-Cyrillus unless there is somerhing I dont know about animation-delay it delays the start of the animation and this would not be useful in my situation. But I will look into it just incase im missing something thanks for the response!

Comment: okay, if the idea is to keep the animation in its last state, then animation-fill-mode: forwards; might be what you need. but if the animation is triggered on hover/not hover you probably need to set that *still* period inside the keyframes on not hover , meaning you probably need animation-fill-mode + another keyframes animation for the reverse effect :(

Comment: @G-Cyrillus no need Ryan Streur pointed out I would be better with a transition then a animation and he was correct its working perfectly now Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure a delay is your best bet here - it sounds like what you're trying to do might be better accomplished with a [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).

Specifically, look at the CSS code for `.box_2`.

```css
transition: all 1s;
```

There's a lot you can do with transitions, but this should get you started.

```css
.box_2 {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.box_2:hover {
  width: 320px;
  height: 420px;
}

.metabox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.box {
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 2em;
}

.box_1 {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}

.box_1:hover {
  animation-name: bigger;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
}
.box_1:not(hover) {
  animation_name: bigger;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
@keyframes bigger {
  from {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
  }
  to {
    width: 310px;
    height: 410px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- example for SO question  -->
<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68594744/is-there-a-wait-function-in-css -->
<div class="metabox">
  <div class="box box_1">Box_1</div>
  <div class="box box_2">Box_2</div>
</div>
```

Also, depending on the context, you may not need the `display: block;` on `.box_1`, since that's the default for block-level elements.

Comment: Thank You! For the `display: block;` I was just trying to fix a bug where it was not displaying but it had nothing to do with display but I just never removed it from my code I will also look into transitions more.